# I am trying to count the frquency of (a'b'c'd'e'f)?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main () {
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int i=1, a, g;
    char alpha ='a';
    fp = fopen("tst.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR : tst.txt");
        return -1;
    }
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {
        for(a=0;a<=5;a++) {
            if(c == 97+a) {
                i++;
            }
            printf("%c = %d\n", 97+a, i);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this

```
 a = 1
    b = 1
    c = 1
    d = 1
    |||||||
    b = 529
    c = 529
    d = 529
    e = 529
    f = 529
    a = 530
    b = 530
    c = 530
    d = 530
    e = 530
    f = 530
    a = 530
    b = 530
    c = 531
    d = 531
    e = 531
    f = 531
    a = 531
    b = 531
    c = 531
    d = 531
    e = 531
    f = 531
    a = 531
    b = 531
    c = 531
    d = 531
    e = 532
    f = 532
    a = 532
    b = 532
    c = 532
    d = 532
    e = 532
    f = 532
    a = 532
    b = 532
    c = 532
    d = 532
    e = 532
    f = 532
    a = 532
b = 532
c = 532
d = 532
e = 532
f = 532
```

desired output =

```
a = 136
b = 32
c = 61
d = 47
e = 220
f = 41
```

IT should be counting the frequency why this is not working
why are these numbers are repeating?
why I am getting this output?

content of tst.txt

```
 In the last problem, you saw an implementation of a simple
"encryption" program.  In this problem, you will write a program
that breaks that encryption---that is, it will take as input
a text file encrypted with the encryption program you just
saw, and prints out the key used to encrypt it!

Breaking the Caesar Cipher uses a technique called "frequency counting."
This technique relies on the fact that the distribution of letters
in the English alphabet is far from uniform: 'e' is by far the most
common letter (~13%), followed by 't' (9%), and 'a' (8%).  Note
that the average frequency is 100/26 ~= 4%.

This frequency distribution means that if you know (or suspect)
that a file contains English text encrypted with a Caesar Cipher,
you can simply count the frequency of all letters in it, and guess
that the letter which occurs most often is 'e'.   Once you know
which letter is 'e', you can backsolve for the key and decrypt
the file.  Note that in practice this requires a large enough
text that "the law of large numbers" applies---and while it is
not guaranteed to work, it typically does.
```

Comment: hi can you my error

Comment: never use magic numbers like 97. Use `'a'` instead

Comment: If you want to count the number of occurrances of 6 different letters, then you will need 6 separate counters. This task is unsolvable with only a single counter.

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what `i` is and why it starts as `1`?

Comment: Use an array of counters. There's no need for the loop, just test if `c` is between `'a'` and `'f'`. Then you can do `counters[c-'a']++;`

Comment: -4 (at the moment) is imho a too harsh rating for a question that, even if it is about very basic concepts, has provided code, desired output and explanation.

Comment: you can ignore unused variables;

Answer (score 0):

While not solving your problem in C, here is an answer using the Ada programming language that should give you some guidance. This solution counts the occurrence of all lower case letters from 'a' through 'z'.

```ada
---
-- count the occurrence of lower case letters in a text document
---

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   subtype lower is Character range 'a' .. 'z';
   type counter is array (lower) of Natural with
      Default_Component_Value => 0;

   Document : File_Type;
   Inpt_Str : String (1 .. 1_024);
   Length   : Natural;
   Counts   : counter;

begin
   Open (File => Document, Mode => In_File, Name => "tst.txt");
   while not End_Of_File (Document) loop
      Get_Line (File => Document, Item => Inpt_Str, Last => Length);
      for value of Inpt_Str (1 .. Length) loop
         if value in lower then
            Counts (value) := Counts (value) + 1;
         end if;
      end loop;
   end loop;
   Close (Document);
   for I in Counts'Range loop
      Put_Line (I'Image & " :" & Natural'Image (Counts (I)));
   end loop;
end Main;
```

The array type named counter is indexed by the characters 'a' through 'z'. Each element of the array is an integer with a minimum value of 0. All elements of the array type are initialized to 0.

After opening the file the program reads the text one line at a time then scans the line for characters within the range of 'a' through 'z'. If the current character is in that range the character is used as the index value into the array Counts, incrementing the array element indexed by the letter.

The last loop simply iterates through the array Counts printing each letter and its corresponding count.

The output of the program is:

```
'a' : 61
'b' : 10
'c' : 31
'd' : 15
'e' : 98
'f' : 20
'g' : 13
'h' : 43
'i' : 61
'j' : 1
'k' : 9
'l' : 36
'm' : 17
'n' : 54
'o' : 50
'p' : 25
'q' : 7
'r' : 51
's' : 46
't' : 99
'u' : 30
'v' : 2
'w' : 15
'x' : 3
'y' : 25
'z' : 0
```